# Python Caesar Cipher Using Ord and Chr

Tags: python, loops

I thought i've learned enough python to make a caesar cipher, so I started making it and i've hit a brick wall.

Here is my code:

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(raw_input("Please enter shift: "))
result = ("Encrypted text is: ")

for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)

    x = x + shift


print chr(x)
```

At the moment if the phrase is 'hi' and shift is 1 , the for loop just loops around the letter i, not the letter h, so my result is: j

I want to loop around the whole word and shift each letter by whatever the shift int variable is.

How can I loop around the phrase variable?

Comment: If it's only outputting one character, and that's the expected last character, what does that tell you about _when_ the `print` statement is taking place?

Comment: Sorry not 100% sure. I've tried putting the print inside the loop and the results were: i,j on separate lines. So it looks like the loop is working, but there's something wrong with the way i'm printing out the info.

Comment: You should also think what is supposed to happen with `az` for instance

Comment: Hi Jon, yeah I was gonna look at that. I'd have to make an if statement so it would go back around to 32 (space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is printing `ord()` value of `'j'` because at the end of loop character is equal to `'i'`. You should store the new characters to a list, and after the end of the loop you should join them and then print.

```
new_strs = []
for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    x = x + shift
    new_strs.append(chr(x))   #store the new shifted character to the list
    #use this if you want z to shift to 'a'
    #new_strs.append(chr(x if 97 <= x <= 122 else 96 + x % 122))
print "".join(new_strs)       #print the new string
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python so.py
Enter text to Cipher: hi
Please enter shift: 1
ij
```

Comment: append is essentially concatenating the shifted characters is that right?

Comment: @BubbleMonster yes, `list.append` appends the items at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Append each encrypted character to the `result` string.

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(raw_input("Please enter shift: "))
result = ""

for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    result += chr(x + shift)

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(raw_input("Please enter shift: "))
result = ("Encrypted text is: ")
import sys
for character in phrase:
  x = ord(character)
  x = x + shift
  sys.stdout.write(chr(x))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```